# Excel, If two columns match on different workbooks, then paste another string column from the 2nd workbook to the 1st workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

How do I tell Excel that if a string column with company names matches another string column with company names from another workbook, then print the Contact Name from the 2nd workbook to the 1st workbook.

Comment: Have you tried using a `VLOOKUP`? If yes, can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1388157/edit) to let us know what it is

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your problem?

Comment: You've got a VLOOKUP tag, so you must have a clue that that is the solution.  What aspect of the problem is causing indigestion?

Answer (score 0):

This matches what is in Cell A2 to sheet 2 column A and returns the result from column 2 (B) from sheet 2.

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

copy and paste down your column B on sheet 1 to pull over the data.  If your contact name is in another column, adjust the numeral "2" to be what column it is in.